# Logged user dissapear in browser refresh

Tags: laravel, vue.js, rest, authentication, vuejs3

I'm working on a project using Vue 3 and Composition API, and I'm developing login function, and it works fine, but when I refresh the page, the logged user dissapear from it and I don´t know why it's happening it. Here´s my userModule file, where I create the ref of the users and some others methods:

```
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue';
import axios from '@/lib/axios';
import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

const credentials = reactive({});
const confirm_password = ref('');
const user = ref({});

const toast = useToast();
const router = useRouter();

const registerUser = async () => {
  const res = await axios.post('api/user/register', credentials);
  toast.success(res.data);
};

const login = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.get('sanctum/csrf-cookie');
    const res = await axios.post('api/user/login', credentials);
    user.value = res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const logout = async () => {
  await axios.post('api/user/logout');
  user.value = null;
};

export default {
  credentials,
  registerUser,
  confirm_password,
  login,
  logout,
  user,
};
```

And here's my login function from backend, using Laravel:

```
public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $validations = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validations && Auth::attempt($request->all())) {
            return response()->json(Auth::user());
        }

        return response()->json([
            'errors' => $validations->errors
        ], 422);
    }
```

Comment: you need to store user information to localStorage or cookie to make it available after refresh page.

Comment: Hi, @SaeidDoroudi is right u need to store ur auth info somewhere and send them with requests that u made. There is an example with Laravel and Next.js that Taylor made. Frontend: https://github.com/taylorotwell/next-example-frontend, backend: https://github.com/taylorotwell/next-example-backend
Maybe check how he does this job and go with that :)

Comment: Thanks for your advices, guys. However, it's happen with any get request I make. Foro example, I make a get request to a "show" method to get a book, I get It perfectly, but when I reload page, it's dissapear. Must I save any data in localStorage or cookie for any requets I make?

Comment: I suggest you should send Auth token to frontend when login. in frontend save token in local storage. then use axios interceptors to inject token header into every request you make

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @kas. Is a big difference if I use API Authentication instead SPA Authentication?